# How to move a mouse using the concept of object tracking in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I was looking online and how people created this virtual mouse application using different principles such as color detector, object tracking, convexity defects etc etc. I wrote this program which actually tracks a single object from a webcam and its actually working really well. Now, the idea is to use this moving object which is being tracked and i want to control my mouse using this application. I dont want the source code and i want to do it myself. But i dont have any clue how to start it. I just hope if you guys can give me some clue or some ideas which can help me to connect my mouse to my program? I want to be able to do left click, right click, double click . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to track an object in the screen then you will get the object co-ordinates & set that as your target co-ordinate. I assume you already did that.

Now set the mouse cursor to that target co-ordinate refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276233/how-to-move-mouse-with-c).

Comment: :- Thanks for your reply. How do i perform right click & left click and double click using the object tracking idea? Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are using VC++ refer this http://www.functionx.com/vcnet/controls/mouse.htm